# Register custom class in Kentico 9

Tags: kentico

I have created a custom gateway class and I need to register this in admin module.

I have added this line in cs file but it throws a namespace error

[assembly: RegisterCustomClass("CustomGateway", typeof(CustomGateway))]

Also in admin -> modules-> e-commerce -> classes tab it says I cannot add or delete class in installed module.

How should I register my customgateway class ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add a `using` statement for the `CMS` namespace in the `.cs` file.

```cs
using CMS;
```

Furthermore, if your `CustomGateway` class is in a custom namespace (let's call it `MyCompany`), you will need to add a `using` statement for that namespace, as well.

```cs
using CMS;
using MyCompany;
```

Regarding the "Classes" tab - the e-commerce classes have nothing to do with registering a custom payment gateway.
As long as you have registered it with the `RegisterCustomClass` attribute, it will be fine.

You can then proceed with setting it up in the "Store configuration" application.

The full docs regarding custom payment gateways can be found [here](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/e-commerce-features/customizing-and-developing-your-store/payment-related-customizing/creating-a-custom-payment-gateway).

Answer (score 0):

You can't register custom payment gateway class in the module in the Admin UI, you can only do it by placing .cs file in your module folder. That will allow to easly export gateway class within your module.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done in 8.2. Example below is for in E-Commerce module. Try it:

```
public partial class CMSModuleLoader
{
    #region "Macro methods loader attribute"

    /// <summary>
    /// Module registration
    /// </summary>
    private class CustomGatewayLoaderAttribute : CMSLoaderAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public CustomGatewayLoaderAttribute()
        {
            // Require E-commerce module to load properly
            RequiredModules = new string[] { ModuleName.ECOMMERCE };
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the module
        /// </summary>
        public override void Init()
        {
            // This line provides the ability to register the classes via web.config cms.extensibility section from App_Code
            ClassHelper.OnGetCustomClass += GetCustomClass;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the custom class object based on the given class name. This handler is called when the assembly name is App_Code.
        /// </summary>
        private static void GetCustomClass(object sender, ClassEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Object == null)
            {
                // Provide your custom classes
                switch (e.ClassName.ToLower())
                {
                    // Define the class CustomGatewayProvider inheriting the CMSPaymentGatewayProvider and you can customize the provider
                    case "customgatewayprovider":
                        e.Object = new CustomGatewayProvider();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```